# django reset sequence for all autofields in a project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In my django project, I have a lot of models. The thing is, I want to make sure the primary key field of all these models starts with `10000` and increments from there. I am using postgresql at the backend. I know that I can run custom sql migrations for every sequence of my models. But when there are a lot of models, this process becomes not so much applicable. Any alternatives to this? thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an automated way; but you shouldn't count on the value of auto increment IDs, and your end users ideally shouldn't see them either. Try to use slugs as user visible identifiers.

Comment: there not much django can do as the auto id property belong to the database side, other than running sql queries i don't think there other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will put the next value of each sequence within the *public* schema to 10000.

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    sq name;
  BEGIN
    FOR sq IN SELECT
      sequencename
    FROM
      pg_sequences
    WHERE
      schemaname = 'public'
    LOOP
      PERFORM setval(sq::regclass, 9999);
    END LOOP;
  END
$$;
```